# Custom component in angular does not update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to learn Angular (Angular 6) and I have created two components, `component-a` and `component-b`. In the template of `component-a` I use `component-b` like this:

```
<component-b [configuration]="selectedConfiguration" *ngIf="selectedConfiguration != null">
    </component-b>
```

where `selectedConfiguration` is a property of `component-a` that is used as an input for `component-b`.

I would have expected that if in the controller of `component-a` I assign a new value to `selectedConfiguration`, like this:

```
this.selectedConfiguration = newConfig;
```

the instance of `component-b` would be recreated, with the new configuration as input, like what happens inside an `ngIf` if you add/remove/replace an item in the underlying array. Instead, nothing happens if I assign a new object to `selectedConfiguration`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try to implement OnChanges in component-b to know if it get changes detection ?
Changes detection works only if you set a new instance of configuration object

Comment: The thing that I suspect is that you are changing the variable `selectedConfiguration` too soon, like in the constructor. Another common problem is that you are out of the scopre of `this`, this happens when you use a plain function in place of an arrow function

Comment: @NicolasLaw-Dune: thanks for your answer, it helped me figure out the problem. I was under the impression that changing the value in component-a would create a new instance of component-b with the new value, but I was wrong. Instead, it just updates the value inside the existing instance of component-b. Knowing this, I changed my code in component-b to react to the change. The reason why I was not seeing any "visual" changes in component-b was because it contains a reactive form, so I have to manually call the method that rebuilds it when the value changes, as it's not directly data-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to close the question, since the solution was found through the comments.

Thanks to NicolasLaw-Dune I've figured out the problem: I was under the impression that changing the value in `component-a` would create a new instance of `component-b` with the new value, but I was wrong. Instead, it just updates the value inside the existing instance of `component-b`. Knowing this, I changed my code in `component-b` to react to the change, by implementing the `OnChanges` interface in `component-b`, checking if the changed value was my input property and updating the component accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in the component-b :

```
export class component-b {
  @Input() configuration: any;

  <some methods with configuration>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. component-b is already defined like in your answer, and it has methods that use `configuration`. The only difference is that I declared the input with a specific type instead of "any". Is that important?

Comment: Not really. I define `any` because I didn't know about the type of `configuration`.